# Can't find tk2toplevel function in any R package

Tags: r, user-interface, tcltk, tcltk2

I am learning how to Develop GUI with R and found this nice [tutorial](http://www.sciviews.org/recipes/tcltk/TclTk-simple-toplevel-window/).

```
library(tcltk2)
win3 <- tk2toplevel(title = "Tk2 window", manage = "grid", padx = 70, pady = 30)
win3$butOK <- tk2button(text = "OK", width = -6, command = TkCmd_destroy(parent))
```

However, the given code throws the following error:

> Error in tk2toplevel(title = "Tk2 window", manage = "grid", padx = 70,
>   :    could not find function "tk2toplevel"

I looked the `tcltk2` documentation and could not find the function `tk2toplevel`. I wonder if this function is coming from some other package.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you; `tk2toplevel` is not available in `tcltk2` and in any other package. 
This is very strange.
In the help `?tk2widgets` this function was never mentioned and the examples contained in this help suggest to use:

```
library(tcltk2)
win3 <- tktoplevel()
butOK <- tk2button(win3, text = "OK", width = -6, command = function() tkdestroy(win3))
tkgrid(butOK)
```

[image]